# BizTalk, TestableReceivePipeline and FileAdapter

Tags: biztalk

I want to test a pipeline which includes a custom component using properties in the message property bag, which at runtime the File Adapter creates. How do I inject those properties in a unit test ?

Comment: Hi Claus what test framework are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I think starting BizTalk Server 2009 there's already a build support for Visual Studio to generate test artifacts for BizTalk Server pipelines.

See this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd792682%28v=bts.10%29.aspx

Also here a very good blog which the author has summarized several way of testing BizTalk Server Artifacts. http://santoshbenjamin.wordpress.com/2009/02/05/biztalk-testing-and-mocks/

Personally, As mentioned by hugh above I'm also using the Tomas Restrepo's pipeline testing framework combined with Moq mocking framework, it has given me an advantage of a more stable and more fluent way of testing Biztalk applications.

Another advantage of http://winterdom.com/2007/08/pipelinetesting11released is if you're using BizUnit for your Unit or Integration testing then it is already supported.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to use Tomas Restrepo's pipeline testing framework:
http://winterdom.com/2007/08/pipelinetesting11released